# Loop Through Cells in sheet and copy values to another sheet if not Empty

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 Sheets `CustomerSupport`, `StandatdMDForm`

i am trying to loop through cells I5 to I84 in `CustomerSupport` sheet

if cell is not empty (contains any name)

copy cell by cell from this row to specific cell destination in `StandardMDForm` Sheet

then print out the `StandardMDForm` Sheet

Here is My Code

```
Sub copyAndPrintMDs()

Dim i As Long

    'Loop through Rows from 5 to 84
    For i = 5 To 84

        'Check if Doctor Name is Available
        If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Cells(i, "I").Value) Then

        'Doctor Details
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("B4").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "I").Value 'Doctor Name
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("B5").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "G").Value 'Potentiality
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("B6").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "H").Value 'Speciality
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("B7").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "E").Value 'City/Area
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("B9").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "J").Value 'Req. Type
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("E5").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "C").Value 'ID
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("E6").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "F").Value 'Clinic
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("E7").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "D").Value 'Rel. Pharmacy
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("B10").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "K").Value 'Req. Details

        'Brand 1
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("B14").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "L").Value 'Brand Name
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("B15").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "M").Value 'Sales
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("B18").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "N").Value 'Value

        'Brand 2
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("C14").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "O").Value
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("C15").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "P").Value
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("C18").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "Q").Value

        'Brand 3
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("D14").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "R").Value
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("D15").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "S").Value
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("D18").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "T").Value

        'Brand 4
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("E14").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "U").Value
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("E15").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "V").Value
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("E18").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "W").Value

        'Brand 5
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("F14").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "X").Value
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("F15").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "Y").Value
        Worksheets("StandardMDForm").Range("F18").Value = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "Z").Value

        'Print MD Sheet
        Sheets("StandardMDForm").PrintOut

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

What's Wrong with it?

Comment: That's good to hear. Did you have a question?

Comment: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: I don't understand -- if you want to copy the non-blank cells, then just copy **all** the cells.  The blank ones don't matter since they don't contain anything.

Comment: @ashleedawg - he wants to fill out a worksheet that looks like a form then printout the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using .Cells(*row, column*) syntax in the .Range definitions.

Change all the,

```
... = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Range(i, "I").Value
```

... to,

```
.... = Worksheets("CustomerSupport").CELLS(i, "I").Value
```

Comment: debug giving me error with this line `If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("CustomerSupport").Cells(i, "I").Value) Then`

Comment: Take off the `.Value`.

Comment: Either the code is not the activeworkbook or the activeworkbook does not have a worksheet named *CustomerSupport*. Look for a trailing space perhaps.

Comment: you are right it's "CustomersSupport". it is working now. Thank you

Comment: what if i want instead of printing out the resulted sheets, To export them all in a single pdf file with today's date as the pdf file name. is it possible?

Comment: You should ask a new question showing the effort you've put in toward a solution and explain the difficulties you are having completing the additional work.